# Swift 2.0 interop with Objective C not working as expected?

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift2, xcode7, xcode7-beta3

I'm porting a Swift 1.2 framework to 2.0. After fixing the 3 million compiler errors courtesy of the new Swift 2.0 error handling scheme, I was finally able to link my test app (written in Objective C) to use the updated framework.

Xcode version 7.0 beta 3 (7A121l)

However, I ran into a problem. Some Swift functions are no longer generated into the automatically generated Objective C header (MyFramework-Swift.h) used by the Objective C test app.

Here is an example of a function that is not exposed: (My actual framework function returned an enum, but I tried to simplify to illustrate the problem more clearly).

```
public func calculateImportantValueDangerously() throws -> Int  
{  
    return 42  
}
```

Note that other functions like the following actually do get exposed as expected (and can be called):

```
public func doSomething()  
{  
}  

public func doSomethingDangerous() throws  
{  
}  

public func calculateMeaninglessValue() -> Int  
{  
    return -1  
}
```

Here's the Objective C side:

```
MyClass *newInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];  
[newInstance doSomething];  

NSError *error = nil;  
[newInstance doSomethingDangerousAndReturnError:&error];  

long meaninglessValue = [newInstance calculateMeaninglessValue];  
NSLog(@"%ld", meaninglessValue);  

long importantValue = [newInstance calculateImportantValueDangerouslyAndReturnError:&error]; <-COMPILE ERROR
NSLog(@"%ld", importantValue);
```

From watching this video, I had expected that it should "just work":

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=401

...but it seems like we can't currently use functions that both throw and return a value.

Is this a bug, or not implemented feature? My apologies if I missed something in the release notes somewhere.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible.

If you annotate your method with `@objc` you will see the problem.

> Throwing method cannot be marked @objc because it returns a value of
>   type 'Int'; return 'Void' or a type that bridges to an Objective-C
>   class

You can return only objects, primitives are not supported.

Comment: Ah I should have been more clear - will update question. I actually looked in the generated MyFramework-Swift.h. The function is not there in the form of calculateImportantValueDangerouslyAndReturnError

Comment: Wow. Good one. My framework class inherited from NSObject, but I guess this wasn't enough to produce a meaningful error message. Marking function with @objc exposed the compile error. Still thinking this sort of sucks.

Answer (score 1):

Although the selected answer is correct; you can't return an Int for a throwing function, I wanted to note an alternate solution since Apple has this same issue for a function in the CoreData framework:

```
func countForFetchRequest(request: NSFetchRequest, error: NSErrorPointer) -> Int
```

Note that in this case Apple is not using the throws pattern and instead reverting to the classic NSError out parameter mechanism.